# Read specfic character from line in Text File(Python)

Tags: python

```
char1= "P"
length=5
f = open("wl.txt", 'r')

for line in f:
if len(line)==length and line.rstrip() == char1:
   z=Counter(line)
   print z
```

I want to output only lines where length=5 and contains character p.So far

```
  f = open("wl.txt", 'r')
    for line in f:
    if len(line)==length :#This one only works with the length
      z=Counter(line)
      print z
```

Any guess someone?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is:

```
if len(line)==length and line.rstrip() == char1:
```

If a line is 5 characters long, then after removing trailing whitespace, you're then comparing to see if it's equal to a string of length 1... 'abcde' is never going to equal 'p' for instance, and your check will never run if your line contains 'p' as it's not 5 characters...

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `Counter`

Corrected code is:

```
# note in capitals to indicate 'constants'
LENGTH = 5
CHAR = 'p'

with open('wl.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # Check length *after* any trailing whitespace has been removed
        # and that CHAR appears anywhere **in** the line
        if len(line.rstrip()) == LENGTH and CHAR in line:
            print 'match:', line
```

Comment: Should have figured you'd be on the case :) +1

Comment: Your solution worked but the match: does not contain character p. Only the length retrieved is 5; I want it to retrieve those containing value p as well and i cross checked the file there are text having character p
i.e
match: their 

match: there 

match: these 

match: price 

match: state

Nevermind mate, i figured it out it is working thanks a lot :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey My spiderpig sense was tingling or something...? :)